# refuse response from server while registering a user on android app

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, android-studio

I'm having a problem registering users on an android app i'm building, i'm getting a refuse response from the server, that's the error i'm getting while  debugging:

```
    <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in <b>/storage/h4/905/1013905/public_html/register.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in <b>/storage/h4/905/1013905/public_html/register.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in <b>/storage/h4/905/1013905/public_html/register.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in <b>/storage/h4/905/1013905/public_html/register.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_store_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in <b>/storage/h4/905/1013905/public_html/register.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in <b>/storage/h4/905/1013905/public_html/register.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in <b>/storage/h4/905/1013905/public_html/register.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in <b>/storage/h4/905/1013905/public_html/register.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in <b>/storage/h4/905/1013905/public_html/register.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in <b>/storage/h4/905/1013905/public_html/register.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in <b>/storage/h4/905/1013905/public_html/register.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
{"success":true}
```

here is my php file:

```
<?php

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "id1013905_user", "MY PASSWORD", "id1013905_trhtkv");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
     function registerUser() {
        global $connect, $name, $age, $username, $password;
        $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO user (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username, $passwordHash);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_close($statement);     
    }
    function usernameAvailable() {
        global $connect, $username;
        $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?"); 
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
        $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_close($statement); 
        if ($count < 1){
            return true; 
        }else {
            return false; 
        }
    }
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  
    if (usernameAvailable()){
        registerUser();
        $response["success"] = true;  
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

the register class i'm using:

```
package com.ben.owner.say_something;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Queue;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText etAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        final EditText etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
        final EditText etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

        bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String name = etName.getText().toString();
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());

                Response.Listener<String>responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                };

                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, age, password,responseListener );
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

register request:

```
package com.ben.owner.say_something;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by owner on 08/03/2017.
 */
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "https://saysomething.000webhostapp.com/register.php";
    private Map<String, String>params;

    public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, int age, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("age", age + "");
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Please help me understand what i'm doing wrong, PHP is not my strong side.

Comment: I'm getting a refuse response from the server

Comment: Remove the port from MySQL host: `$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", ...);`. MySQL uses 3306 as its default port. If you use `localhost` to connect to your MySQL instance, the MySQL client may use a Unix socket and the port is not required. Also check if the MySQL server is running and not blocked by a firewall.

Comment: I removed the port from MySQL host as u said and now i'm getting this error:                                                                                                             <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'id1013905_user'@'2a02:4780:bad:f00d::2' (using password: YES) in <b>/storage/h4/905/1013905/public_html/register.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />

Comment: Getting the same error as before

Comment: What are you using local server environment? Mamp, Wamp or Xampp or ....?

Comment: im using 000webhost; i just saw that my host name is not localhost its:files.000webhost.com I've changed that but i'm still getting the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137638/discussion-between-vanloc-and-ben-shabat).

Comment: @vanloc yes its working...i have no idea what i've changed but im using localhost.

Comment: Cheer. When I config in my host, I also add host name is `localhost`. But I read in 000webhost document(with free account), can't do that. So, too much comment to resolve your problem. Finally, it working. Congratulation @BenShabat. :)

Comment: @vanloc Thank you , I'm facing another problem i'll appreciate if you could see the next post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692751/login-not-working-on-androip-app