# Login not working on androip app

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

Hi i'm building an app on android studio which requires register and login,
My registration working fine while i'm having troubles with my login,I'm getting false boolean instead of true even if the username and password are correct,
Here my PHP file:

```
`$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id1013905_trhtkv", "my password",` "id1013905_user");


    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colUserID, $colName, $colUsername, $colAge, $colPassword);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        if (password_verify($password, $colPassword)) {
            $response["success"] = true;  
            $response["name"] = $colName;
            $response["age"] = $colAge;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

My login activity:

```
package com.ben.owner.say_something;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        final Button bLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        final TextView registerLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterHere);

        registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });

        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                final Response.Listener<String>responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success){
                                String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                                int age = jsonResponse.getInt("age");
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name",name);
                                intent.putExtra("username",username);
                                intent.putExtra("age",age);
                                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                };
                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username,password,responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

And my login request:

```
package com.ben.owner.say_something;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by owner on 09/03/2017.
 */
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "https://saysomething.000webhostapp.com/Login.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest(String username,String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Comment: password_verify — Verifies that a password matches a hash. Please compare their values

Comment: @SandeepKharat The password matches

Comment: where it fails?

Comment: @Vyacheslav I'm getting from the server false so i'm guessing i'm not getting into the while loop in the php file

Comment: Hi @BenShabat, I'm here. Can you show values of `$colPassword`? `password_verify (string $password , string $hash)`. Make sure `$colPassword` is a hash string.

Comment: @vanloc hi all the values returning null for some reason

Comment: @vanloc $statement returns false

Comment: @Vyacheslav thats what im getting when i'm echo json_encode($statement) - 
`{"affected_rows":null,"insert_id":null,"num_rows":null,"param_count":null,"field_count":null,"errno":null,"error":null,"error_list":null,"sqlstate":null,"id":null}`

Comment: Ok, I see your PHP file to check login not correct. Please read: http://codingcyber.com/simple-login-script-php-and-mysql-64/

Comment: @BenShabat ... and you print again result. I think your PHP check is fail.

Answer (score 0):

To find your bug I just would suggest to retrieve server values in the responce.

I mean

instead of

```
$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    if (password_verify($password, $colPassword)) {
        $response["success"] = true;  
        $response["name"] = $colName;
        $response["age"] = $colAge;
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

use

```
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  
echo $statement;//or something like
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){

        if (password_verify($password, $colPassword)) {

echo $password;
echo $colPassword;
            $response["success"] = true;  
            $response["name"] = $colName;
            $response["age"] = $colAge;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
```

or debug your server side. It seems your server code is wrong.

check this example

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: that the response im getting:
 '{"success":false} 
,so i guess im not going into the if statment for some reason